# How to capitalise the first word of a sentence if it's been elided?

Tags: capitalization, formality, abbreviations

The example I have just come across:

```
'fraid we don't do it that way anymore.
```

Or should it be:

```
'Fraid we don't do it that way anymore.
```

Using either 'fraid is casual anyway because it should (more formally) read "I'm afraid.." so maybe it doesn't really matter but I just got curious.

Follow up question: are there more formal examples where this does come up?

Comment: Edited the title. [*Elision*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elision) is the term used for omitting an initial or final letter or syllable. They are not generally called abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks @bib, already learned something and I don't even have an answer yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it begins a sentence, yes, it should be capitalized. Capitalization aids readability--it is a clear indication of where a sentence begins. Many people have many opinions about the so-called rules of grammar, but as far as I know, agreement that a sentence should begin with a capital letter is universal,* except perhaps in some poetic instances. Even there, you will see in Shakespeare:

*'Tis now the very witching time of night*

Also (not in Shakespeare),

*'Twas the night before Christmas.*

As for the word *afraid*, Merriam-Webster includes the variant *fraid,* without the apostrophe. If it's the apostrophe that's throwing you off, it many cases it can be eliminated without causing confusion, but whether you include it or not, the first letter of a sentence is always upper case.

*One possible exception is the use of trademarks like iPod and eBay. Some style guides insist on the capitalizing the first letter, while some don't. This really is a matter of editorial choice. Because the second letter of these trademarks is upper case, many feel the readability issue is not compromised by keeping the first letter small. However, there are some trade marks that include no capital letters at all, and which, furthermore, are common, everyday words. These almost always must be capitalized to avoid confusion--but again this is an editorial decision based on a publication's relationship with its advertisers, its readers, etc.